# Stylish Sliding Menu With JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, slideshow

I am using Stylish Sliding Menu With JQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
        $('ul.child').hide();
        $('ul.parent a.slide').click(function(){
        $('ul.child').slideUp('slow');
        $(this).next().find('a').show();
        $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
        return false;
        });
        });
        </script>

        <ul class="parent">
        <li>
        <a href="#" class="slide">Title One</a>
        <ul class="child">
        <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

Sliding menu is working fine.But in this last opened 'child ul' Will not close after opened.I have to reset all after some time.Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/fd46R/

```
 $(function(){
    $('ul.child').hide();
    $('ul.parent a.slide').click(function(){
    $('ul.child').slideUp('slow');
    $(this).next().find('a').show();
        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
    $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
        }
    return false;
    });
    });​
```

Comment: I have to hide all child of opened parent after some time $('ul.child').hide();

Comment: @Advitha : I have updated the fiddle to hide the last opened set after few seconds of delay. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

See this is the updated code which opens the .child and waits for 1000 ms (1 sec) and then slides up.

> **http://jsfiddle.net/fBYNy/3/**

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.child').hide();
    $('ul.parent li').click(function() {
        $('ul.child',this).slideDown('slow').delay(1000).slideUp('fast');
    //                               -----^^^^^^^^^^---- this will slide 
    //                              the opened menu after 1 second of delay            
        $(this).next().children('.child').slideUp('fast');
        $(this).prev().children('.child').slideUp('fast');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I have to hide all child of opened parent after some time $('ul.child').hide();

Comment: you mean sliding up after 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: ya..now this will show opened parent and child until we refresh the page.I have to close it after some time or in a next click  on parent